Websockets not working in Quart using Blueprints
`i'm trying to initialize a websocket connection with the Broker class using Blueprints but it seems that it's not getting any response back only 400 error and this :
WebSocket error:
error { target: WebSocket, isTrusted: true, srcElement: WebSocket, currentTarget: WebSocket, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, returnValue: true, defaultPrevented: false, composed: false, … }
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
explicitOriginalTarget: WebSocket { url: "ws://dev.localhost:5000/ws", readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, … }
isTrusted: true
originalTarget: WebSocket { url: "ws://dev.localhost:5000/ws", readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, … }
returnValue: true
srcElement: WebSocket { url: "ws://dev.localhost:5000/ws", readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, … }
target: WebSocket { url: "ws://dev.localhost:5000/ws", readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, … }
timeStamp: 905322
type: "error"
app. py :
if __name__ == "__main__":

    from routes.ws_bp import ws_bp as wbp

    app.register_blueprint(wbp)

ws.py :
import asyncio
from typing import AsyncGenerator
from quart import Quart

class Broker:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.connections = set()

async def publish(self, message: str) -> None:
    for connection in self.connections:
        await connection.put(message)

async def subscribe(self) -> AsyncGenerator[str, None]:
    connection = asyncio.Queue()
    self.connections.add(connection)
    try:
        while True:
            yield await connection.get()
    finally:
        self.connections.remove(connection)
broker = Broker()

ws_bp.py :
from quart import Blueprint, websocket
import asyncio
from services.ws import broker

ws_bp = Blueprint('ws_bp', __name__)


async def _receive() -> None:
    while True:
        message = await websocket.receive()
        await broker.publish(message)


@ws_bp.websocket('/ws')
async def ws() -> None:
    try:
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(_receive())
        async for message in broker.subscribe():
            await websocket.send(message)
    finally:
        task.cancel()
        await task

react frontend-server :
const { sendMessage, lastMessage, readyState } = useWebSocket('ws://dev.localhost:5000/ws', {
  onOpen: () => {
    console.log('WebSocket connection established.');
  },
  onMessage: (message) => {
    console.log('Received message:', message);
  },
  onClose: () => {
    console.log('WebSocket connection closed.');
  },
  onError: (error) => {
    console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
  },
  shouldReconnect: (closeEvent) => true,
});
return (
     <div>
     <button onClick={() => sendMessage('Hello from client!')}>Send Message</button>
    {lastMessage ? <p>Last message: {lastMessage.data}</p> : <p>No messages received yet. </p>}
    </div> )`


This may not be the answer you are looking for, but It could help someone, or at least help diagnose the problem. I had a similar issue and I walked my way back stripping my app.


import quart_flask_patch

from typing import Any
from quart import Quart
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from .config import configenv
from quart_cors import cors, route_cors
from quart_rate_limiter import RateLimiter


def create_app(configname:str , namespaces: list) -> Quart:
    '''Create app module and initialization of core packages'''
    app: Any = Quart(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(configenv[configname])

    from app import models
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db, render_as_batch=True)
    rate_limiter.init_app(app)
    
    # cors(app) # !!! This was my mistake !!!
    
    from app.api import api as api_blueprint
    from app.webhooks import webhook as webhook_blueprint

    app.register_blueprint(api_blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(webhook_blueprint, url_prefix='/webhook')
    app.register_blueprint(rq_dashboard.blueprint, url_prefix="/api/rq")

    return app



In my case, I noticed it was a CORS (cross origin resource sharing) issue. Try commenting cors, If you must use cors, make sure you implement it properly. If you are using the quart_cors package, make sure you restrict cors to routes my using the route_cors module.
from quart_cors import route_cors

